# Dynamically update 'amount' on PayPal button/iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, paypal

I've been tasked with building a checkout page with one requirement: It must use PayPal for checkout. The problem I have is, the amount is completely variable... the user can select the amount they wish to purchase (e.g. purchasing a £100 gift code).

PayPal generally renders their buttons/iframes on page load, meaning the amount is set.

`<input type="hidden" name="subtotal" value="50">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">`

When the user attempts to pay, the price would be fixed at 50 GBP

I need to be able to alter this so that the amount the user enters will be the amount they pay. On my checkout page, I have an amount field where the user can enter any value... is it possible to get PayPal to accept this value?

I've tried dynamically (with Javascript) changing the value of `subtotal` input and then removing the iframe and creating a new one with the same data... this simply renders a blank iframe.

```
document.getElementById("paypal-iframe").setAttribute('value','25');

var elem = document.querySelector('#paypal-iframe');
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);

// create new iframe...
```

The initial PayPal code looks like this:

```
<iframe name="hss_iframe" id="paypal-iframe" height="540px" width=100%" style="border: none; max-width: 100%; margin:0;padding:0"></iframe>
<form style="display:none" target="hss_iframe" name="form_iframe" method="post"
      action="https://securepayments.paypal.com/...">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_hosted-payment">
    <input type="hidden" name="subtotal" value="50">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="XXX">
    <input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" value="sale">
    <input type="hidden" name="template" value="mobile-iframe">
    <input type="hidden" name="solution_type" value="Sole">
</form>
```

I think the last resort could be to add another page... let user select amount and then submit it to a new page, but would prefer to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

This...

`document.getElementById("paypal-iframe").setAttribute('value','25');`

...won't work.  You can't alter any DOM nodes inside the `<iframe>` because it violates same-origin policy.

You could add your own form and have it alter the value of `subtotal` in the paypal form before it's submitted:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="paypal-price">
<button id="donate">pay</button>

<iframe name="hss_iframe" id="paypal-iframe" height="540px" width=100%" style="border: none; max-width: 100%; margin:0;padding:0"></iframe>
<form style="display:none" target="hss_iframe" name="form_iframe" method="post"
      action="https://securepayments.paypal.com/...">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_hosted-payment">
    <input type="hidden" name="subtotal" value="50">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="XXX">
    <input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" value="sale">
    <input type="hidden" name="template" value="mobile-iframe">
    <input type="hidden" name="solution_type" value="Sole">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
document.querySelector('button#pay').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('form[name="form_iframe"] input[name="subtotal"]').value = document.querySelector('input#paypal-price').value;
  document.querySelector('form[name="form_iframe"]').submit();
});
```